# SQL convert some column names to row values and one column name row values to column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have a table organized as follows:

```
Year |Account | Location| Measure1 |Measure2 |Measure3 

2020 |123a    |A       |100      |20%        |5
2020 |234b    |B       |75       |80%        |8
2020 |122c    |C       |80       |78%        |9
```

I want to create records as follows:

```
Year  |Account | Measure      |A    |B     |C

2020  |123a     |Measure1    |100   |      |
2020  |
2020  |234b     |Measure2    |      |80%   |
2020  |122c     |Measure3    |      |      |9
```

Comment: Why are all 3 records in the expected result set being associated with account `123a`?  What happened to the other 2 accounts?

Comment: Explain how that second row appears with only a value for year.

Answer (score 0):

This forum isn't for solving your programming tasks. But for the fun of it:

```
select Year, Account, 'Measure1' as Measure, Measure1 as A, null as B, null as C
from my_table
where Location = 'A'

union

select Year, Account, 'Measure2' as Measure, Measure2 as A, null as B, null as C
from my_table
where Location = 'A'

...

union

select Year, Account, 'Measure1' as Measure, null as A, Measure1 as B, null as C
from my_table
where Location = 'B'

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `APPLY`:

```
select t.year, t.account, v.*
from t cross apply
     (values ('Measure1', Measure1, null, null),
             ('Measure2', null, Measure2, null),
             ('Measure3', null, null, Measure3)
     ) v(measure, a, b, c);
```

This returns all but the second row.  It is not clear what logic you want for that, but you can add:

```
union all
select distinct t.year, null, null, null, null, null
```

To add it explicitly.